# MS Access crosstab query with criteria

Tags: ms-access, crosstab

My database has three fields: Location (string), Date (MM/DD/YYYY), and bird_species (string). I'm trying to create a crosstab query that counts the number of times one particular species is seen at each location and date. A species is recorded at the location when it is seen, and if more than one of the species is seen at that location, it is recorded on its own line with the same date and location. The desired output I'm trying to achieve would look something like this:

Location 1/11/2020 1/12/2020 1/13/2020 1/14/2020 1/30/2020 2/1/2020

A                         2         1         4         0          8        0

B                          1         1         3         0          2        0

C           0         5         1         1          1        0

D           0         0         0         0          0        0

I have a couple of issues 1) how do I make a crosstab query with criteria? I've successfully made a crosstab query that counts all observations (of all species) at all locations and dates and that works. 2) How do I make sure all locations and dates are included, even if the count = 0? I've used a cross tab query that queries a select query for a particular species, but that eliminates Location 'D' and 2/1/2020 (the last row in my example) because there are no observations for that species at that location or on that date.

P.S. sorry for the formatting...best I can do with the editor WYSIWYG

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html

Comment: the question seems too generic. consider asking a more specific question. this seems like an extremely open ended question.

Comment: Ok I'll break it down into the smallest, most direct questions I can. First, how do I set a criterion for a crosstab query? For example, if I had a database with Date, Salesperson, and Shoe Brand in a table, and I wanted to look at how many pairs of Nikes were sold on every day for the past year by each Salesperson, how would I make a crosstab to just count the number of pairs of Nikes (including a count when a salesperson sold no Nikes on a particular day).